# FIRDatabaseQuery not finding data , how to debug this

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am batteling to find any data when I perform this query on the data.

the data struct is as follows:

```
users:
       id_123 : 
                name: "name a"
                surname: "surname a"
       id_124 : 
                name: "name b"
                surname: "surname b"
```

-

```
// Find user by id
FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"users"];
FIRDatabaseQuery *qry = [ref queryEqualToValue:@"id_123"];

[qry observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded
            withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

                // THE DEBUGGER NEVER GETS HERE...
                NSLog(@"snapshot: %@", snapshot);

                NSDictionary *user = [snapshot value]; 

                //get user details:
                NSString *name = [user valueForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *surname = [user valueForKey:@"surname"];

}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to read a child node.

```
FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"users"];
FIRDatabaseReference *user = [ref child:@"id_123"];

[user observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
```

Queries "skip a level", so you'd only need a query if you want to filter `name` or `surname`.

Comment: Great thanks for the help. Worked 100%, one strange thing though.
The event fires twice , once for name and once more for surname.

Comment: Oops.... the `ChildAdded` was a remnant from the query. You should use `Value` events for this. I updated the code.

Comment: Hi Frank, is it possible to do wild card queries?  
Say I want to find all records that have id's in a certain range, e.g child[@"id_12%"]

Comment: Yes, you can get all keys starting with `id_12`. But in [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054550/firebase-database-how-to-perform-a-prefix-wildcard-query) you asked something slightly different.