# Firebase Database - How to perform a prefix wildcard query

Tags: android, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to perform wildcard queries on a Firebase database,
and do not know whether the libraries support this. - (my guess it does not.)

I want an optimal solution where the network traffic will be as little as possible, assume the dataset is millions of records.

Dataset (using prefix wildcard):

```
user_id:
         id_001123:      
                   name: "java"
         id_002124:
                   name: "objective-c"
         id_003125:
                   name: "swift"
```

How would the code look like to retrieve the record id_002124 name field  using a wildcard, you only have a portion of the id. eg. "%124".

The expected result would be id_002124, and the name being "objective-c"

Any mobile language example code would great. 
(Objective-C/Swift/Java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase Database queries can order/filter data based on the object's keys (e.g. `id_001123`), their values (doesn't apply in your case), or the value of a child property (e.g. the fact that `name` = `"java"`).

For each of these Firebase can match items that have a specific value you specify, items starting at a value you specify, or items ending at a value you specify.

So you can create a query matching the item named `objective-c` with:

```
ref.child("user_id").orderByChild("name").equalTo("objective-c")
```

Or you can create a query matching `id_001124` and `id_001125` with:

```
ref.child("user_id").orderByKey().startAt("id_001125")
```

Or simply getting all items starting with `id_0011`:

```
ref.child("user_id").orderByKey().startAt("id_0011")
```

Or you can create a query matching `id_001123` and `id_001124` with:

```
ref.child("user_id").orderByKey().endAt("id_001124")
```

Firebase Database cannot filter based on the end of a value. So there is no way in your current data structure to get all items whose key ends in a `4`.

Please read more about Firebase Database queries here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

And see some of the many previous questions about searching for FirebaseL

- [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase)
- [Firebase query - Find item with child that contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string)
- [Firebase "like" search on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951076/firebase-like-search-on-string/42953600#42953600)