# Search Query In Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
 from client side how can i search by **businessName** in firebase all record like when i write *ka* then kashif, kaleem, related data will be show to me.

Comment: You can query startingAt("ka").endingAt("ka\uf8ff"") and that will return all of the businesses starting with ka; kaschif, kaleem etc.

Comment: The *\uf8ff* component is a character high in the unicode table, so it's essentially querying for starting "ka" and ending "ka"+high unicode char. It gives some flexibility in queries for finding words starting with a specific string. Substring searches are a bit more complex but if they are single words, can be done by [brute force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870425/swift-how-can-i-use-shouldchangetextinrange-with-firebase-for-real-time-sear/36872475#36872475) or if you want a lot of flexibility for larger strings [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't support this (yet?). You'd have to download all data and make your own local search function.
Firestore has improved on Firebase's query ability, but only a little. All-in-all, querying power is Firebase's fatal weakness.

Comment: This answer is not accurate. You can query startingAt("ka").endingAt("ka\uf8ff"") and that will return all of the businesses starting with ka;  kaschif, kaleem etc. Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054550/firebase-database-how-to-perform-a-prefix-wildcard-query) for some other options.

Comment: @Jay wow, your solution worked, could you explain `\uf8ff`, is this indicating regex?
Also, this solution only works if the letters match from the start.
Like if i write 'u', it won't search for `Junaid`, `Qumber`...